# How to get the last inserted row when I Group by column in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I run this query to get me the active users in a duration of 10 minutes. the `clicks` table has multiple rows of a `user` with each `page`. I can get the list of `user` but the `page` next to the output is not the last row, but the first.

That means if 4 rows are stored for a specific `user`, 1st is 1 minute ago, and the 4th is 8 minutes ago, it will show me the 8th minute `page`, not the 1st minute `page`.

How to fix this ?

```
SELECT user
     , page 
  FROM clicks 
 WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE 
 GROUP 
    BY user
 ORDER 
    BY id DESC
```

Comment: Just FYI, this IS the most frequently asked question under the mysql tag on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 select temp.*
from
(
 select user , page
 from clicks
 order by timestamp desc
) temp

group by temp.user;
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of this hack, but (at least up until v.5.6) it does at least work

Comment: Yes it worked in (at least up until v.5.6) but it does not work for upper versions. Still it is good answer)

Answer (score 4):

This will work for all versions

```
SELECT 
    id, tc_stage_id, user
FROM
    clicks
WHERE
    id IN (SELECT 
        MAX(id)
    FROM
        clicks
    GROUP BY user)
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql_insert_id
Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your answer is very short, and would probably benefit from a link to documentation and / or a code sample. For example, it looks like you mean to suggest the PHP function mysql_insert_id(), but that is not immediately obvious.